# 1x image comes for ipad rather than 3x in Universal Application

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcasset

I have set images in Xcassets for a universal app for 1x,2x & 3x. its dimensions comes as 44*44 , 88 *88, 132*132. Some images comes correct for iPad but some comes as small ???? iPhone pics comes fine in all !!

Does any one has any suggestion ??

Comment: 3x is not for iPad, only for iPhone Plus. r u sure you're not using a non-retina iPad? like ipad before 3rd gen or iPad mini 1

Comment: @ronan I am checking on simulator

Comment: Are they displayed small? Or low-resolution?

Comment: @ronan Yaa it looks small